# где можно создавать экземпляры классов помимо метода Main?

Tags: c#, объекты

есть статический метод `Main` как точка входа в программу,
и во всех примерах объекты регистрируются именно в нем.
Можно ли создавать объекты (регистрировать ссылки на объект)
типа `AСlass mya = new AClass();` не в методе `Main`, а просто внутри других классов ?

Например

```
BClass{
    /* ... */
    AСlass mya = new AClass();
}
```

Comment: Хм. По-моему, легче перечислить, где **нельзя** создавать объекты классов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Например - в конструкторе или любом методе.

```
BClass
{ 
    private AClass aClass;
    public BClass() {
        this.aClass = new AClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно ли сказать что объекты создаются в пределах области видимости namaspase   - и можно создать в любом месте кода ?

Comment: нет. Объекты создаются только в методах(функциях).

Answer (score 0):

объекты необходимо создавать там где они будут использоваться